Displaying a specific graph from a multi-faceted dataframe
I am fairly new-ish to R/RStudio so I apologies in advance for any lack of seemingly obvious knowledge and thank you in advanced for any help in this.
I am trying to create a Rmarkdown document in HTML that will have a drop down that will display a specific graph given a value in a drop down. I have made the data frame which has the following structure:
>    year  refer  month_of  freq
> 1  2024  ABC    Jan       20
> 2  2024  DEF    Jan       2
> 3  2024  GHI    Jan       56
> 4  2024  JKL    Jan       19
> 5  2024  MNO    Jan       121
> 6  2024  ABC    Feb       35
> 7  2024  DEF    Feb       6
> 8  2024  GHI    Feb       70
> 9  2024  JKL    Feb       25

Datatypes:
year - char
refer - char
month_of - Factor
freq - number
Here is the code I have so far to get to this dataframe:
library(tidyverse)
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
library(reshape2)
library(ggforce)

# loads the data from a csv generated from a MSSQL Script

pivot_table <- read_csv("C:\\My\\Folder\\pivot_table_latest.csv")

# removing the last line in the table which are just dud characters. I did try to put this into the second pipe but that did not work so I had to separate it

pivot_table <- pivot_table \[-1,,drop=F\]

# removes the first line of data and changes the data recorded to numeric except the year

pivot_table <- pivot_table %\>%
    filter(row_number() \<= n()-2) %\>%
    mutate_at(c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'July', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'), as.numeric)

# makes the data long

pivot_table <- melt(pivot_table)

#changes the name of the columns and changes the month column to a factor data type making it possible to display on a line graph

pivot_table <- pivot_table %\>%
    rename(month_of = variable) %\>%
    rename(freq = value) %\>%
    mutate(month_of = factor(month_of, levels = unique(month_of)))

# displays the line graphs facet wrapped using facet_wrap_paginate

ggplot(pivot_table , aes(x=month_of, y=freq, group = refer)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_point() +
    facet_wrap_paginate(\~refer, ncol = 2, nrow = 3) +
    ggtitle("Graph Title") +
    xlab("Month") +
    ylab("Frequency")


I can facet wrap them so they show all the separate graphs for each "Reference" on one page and even display them on a larger scale using facet_wrap_paginate but what I want to do is just display one of the graphs given this data set.

Is there a way of doing this without separating the dataframe into 40 smaller frames? (as this would be a nightmare if an extra reference is added to the database I have)
And can this be implemented into an Rmarkdown document that will have a dropdown box so someone can look at each graph given the value in the dropdown box?

General notes and context:

the column names are not the actual names in the frame but they describe what data they hold within the context of the problem
the year is a char datatype as it saves as that when importing into RStudio from a CSV and I don't need to change it to a number as it is never used as a number
the reference column values can have "/" and "=" in them as well but are always 3 characters long
the month column is a factor datatype due to it importing as a pivot table and having to change it to long data means it won't save as a date datatype



I did try the facet_wrap_paginate route of 1 column and 40 rows and see if that would work but quickly realised that it would mean saving it as a separate image as a certain name for the HTML document to reference and then code that to display x distance down said document given the dropdown box value but if a new reference is created (of which certainly will happen in the future) then the whole code will probably have to be uprooted and redone so I am looking at a more generalised route in this case (adding an extra value to a dropdown is not an issue in this case BUT if there is a way to also make the unique values in the dropdown box use the reference column automatically that would be awesome but that is not a must).
